# How to find target architecture and append it to target name?

Tags: windows, cmake

I want to be able to deploy both x64 as well as x86 binaries of a project into the same directory. To enable this, the target names need to be different (e.g. `foo_x86` and `foo_x64`). However, I couldn't find a clean way to determine the target architecture.

This is my naïve implementation:

```
project(foo)

set(TARGET_NAME foo_${MSVC_CXX_ARCHITECTURE_ID})
add_executable(${TARGET_NAME} WIN32 foo.cpp)
```

There are many issues with this, the most blatant one being, that it will only work with a single compiler. Is there a cleaner/better/more CMake-like way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Does [CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR.html) or [CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR.html) suit your needs?

Comment: As documented, [CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR.html) holds *"the name of the CPU CMake is building for."* Unfortunately, that doesn't appear to be true when using Visual Studio. It consistently returns `AMD64`, irrespective of the target architecture.